# User::where(user->id==$profile->id); get profile that is equal to user in controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

If you set relation ships between the `User.php return $this->belongsTo('App\User');` and `Profile.php return $this->hasOne('App\Profile', 'user_id', 'id');` how can u get a corresponding user to the profile when you only get the Profile variables. `public function update(Request $request, Profile $profile)`

i was thinking of something like this `User::where(user->id==$profile->id);` but its not working how would can you do it?

mine hole function:

```
if(\Auth::check()) {

        if(\Auth::user()->type == 'admin'){

            $validated = $request->validate([

                'username' => 'required',

                'email' => 'required|email',

                'firstname' => 'required',

                'lastname' => 'required',

                'age' => 'required|numeric|max:150',

                'birthdate' => 'required|numeric',

                'bio' => 'required|min:30',

                'select_file'  => 'image|mimes:jpg,png,gif,jpeg|max:2048'

            ]);

            $image = $request->file('select_file');
            $new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move(public_path('images'), $new_name);

            $profile->username      = $validated['username'];
            $profile->email         = $validated['email'];
            $profile->firstname     = $validated['firstname'];
            $profile->lastname      = $validated['lastname'];
            $profile->age           = $validated['age'];
            $profile->birthdate     = $validated['birthdate'];
            $profile->bio           = $validated['bio'];
            $profile->image_path    = $new_name;
            $profile->update();

            $user                   = User::where(user->id==$profile->id);
            $user->name             = $validated['username'];
            $user->email            = $validated['email'];
            $user->update();

            return redirect()
                ->route('admin')
                ->with('succes', 'Profile updated succesfully');
        } else {

            return redirect()
                ->route('admin')
                ->with('fail', 'Profile is unable to be update successfully');
        }
    } else {

        return redirect()
            ->route('login')
            ->with('fail', 'Profile is unable to be update successfully 
    because ur not an Admin');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it some ways.

Solution 1:

```
User::whereId($profile->user_id)->first();
```

Solution 2:

```
User::where('id', $profile->user_id)->first();
```

Solution 3:

```
User::where('id','=', $profile->user_id)->first();
```

Solution 4:

```
User::where(['id' => $profile->user_id])->first();
```

Also you can do it 
In Profile model define

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Than you can lazy load

```
$user = $profile->load('user')->user; // but it is lazy loading
```

Comment: there all giving this error Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message

Comment: @HashtagForgotName That's totally unrelated, and means you're `POST`ing to a `GET` route (or `GET` to `POST`, etc.)

Comment: You must be fix it in your `routes/web.php` file

Comment: It was an put forgot to add in the form its fixed now

Answer (score 2):

Your where is not formatted properly. You need to pass in 2 (or 3) parameters, where the first is the column, and the second is the value you're checking for. If using 3 parameters, the second would be the operator (`=` or `!=`). Don't forget `first()` (for one record) or `get()` (for a collection of records), so that the query actually runs. Otherwise, it will just be the QueryBuilder object.

```
User::where('id', $profile->user_id)->first();
```

or

```
User::where('id','=', $profile->user_id)->first();
```

Since you're checking against the user's id, you can also use `find()` to get one record:

```
User::find($profile->user_id);
```

Comment: $profile has column  `user_id`. Please fix your answer

Comment: @Davit  No, profile has the user_id. User has id. *edit* Never mind... I see what you mean now

Comment: `User::find($profile->id);`  it must be `User::find($profile->user_id);`